# Arcpy if statement to act on layers at the top level of hierarchy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I am about to save copies of all of the layers in my mxd. I only want to save the top level group layers though. I have some group layers within group layers - I dont want to save them individually. So far I can export all group layers like this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
 if lyr.isGroupLayer == True:
     lyr.saveACopy(lyr.name.replace(":"," -").replace("&","and").replace(">","") + ".lyr")
```

What I'm looking for is either a property that says what level the layer is on so I could say `if layer level = top level...`  (instread of `if lyr.isGroupLayer == True:`) or a property that says that the layer is within a group layer so I could say `if lyr.isInGroupLayer == False:`.

I suppose this could be in my for loop or a change to the mapping.ListLayers

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check, longName property of the layer to see whether it has backslashes or not:

Here is the snippet:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.isGroupLayer == True:
        if lyr.longName.find('\\') == -1:
            print lyr.longName
```

I hope it helps